# Google Sheets: Possible to set conditional formatting based on contents of a different cell also using a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a schedule-type sheet with an updating weekday value (one cell with `=TODAY()`, one cell referencing the date cell with `=TEXT(A1, "ddd")`, converting the weekday value into a 3-letter text format).

I have events listed on the sheet with dates they happen on ("Event: Sun/Mon/Thu/Fri" for example) in the cell value, and I would like that cell to change to a different color if today's weekday matches up with one of the weekdays listed in the cell value by referencing the automatically-updating cell with the weekday text. Is this possible in Google Sheets? I tried using "format cells if text contains" and specifying the cell but that didn't seem to work.

Example sheet in case this was confusing - short explanation added to notes in cell B1.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/104tvkto1nNhNGDSjBtIPiRrHwPN4--QKeA_Qfx13niI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a spreadsheet with the conditional formatting filled in for Column D.
Keep in mind that today() is not a live formula, meaning it only updates if the worksheet needs to do calculations. If the worksheet doesn't need to update, then there's a chance the date there could be wrong.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15HtuBxigb69LKK3clMuhpd1RmTPJbr4Zu0axZ9F31To/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. While a link to an spreadsheet might be helpful, posts in this site should be self contained as the spreadsheet, the same as occurs with any other linked result, might not be available later making the post unhelpful. In other words, please add  into the answer the direction to set the conditional formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed! :D